# Why Memcached is empty

Tags: php, php-fpm, memcached, php-memcached

I've added memcached to LAMP stackand Wordpress and everything seems fine except the memcached memory is empty.
When I check with **memcdump --servers=127.0.0.1** it returns nothing. Also when I connect via **telnet 127.0.0.1 11211** it seems to be running but empty - **stats items** return nothing and

stats slabs

```
STAT active_slabs 0
STAT total_malloced 0
```

What am I missing here?

Below are all the checks I've done

memcached **stats** full output

```
stats
STAT pid 37127
STAT uptime 12198
STAT time 1706711922
STAT version 1.5.22
STAT libevent 2.1.11-stable
STAT pointer_size 64
STAT rusage_user 1.447142
STAT rusage_system 0.916591
STAT max_connections 1024
STAT curr_connections 1
STAT total_connections 14
STAT rejected_connections 13
STAT connection_structures 2
STAT reserved_fds 20
STAT cmd_get 1
STAT cmd_set 0
STAT cmd_flush 0
STAT cmd_touch 0
STAT cmd_meta 0
STAT get_hits 0
STAT get_misses 1
STAT get_expired 0
STAT get_flushed 0
STAT delete_misses 0
STAT delete_hits 0
STAT incr_misses 0
STAT incr_hits 0
STAT decr_misses 0
STAT decr_hits 0
STAT cas_misses 0
STAT cas_hits 0
STAT cas_badval 0
STAT touch_hits 0
STAT touch_misses 0
STAT auth_cmds 0
STAT auth_errors 0
STAT bytes_read 11417
STAT bytes_written 6580
STAT limit_maxbytes 67108864
STAT accepting_conns 1
STAT listen_disabled_num 0
STAT time_in_listen_disabled_us 0
STAT threads 4
STAT conn_yields 0
STAT hash_power_level 16
STAT hash_bytes 524288
STAT hash_is_expanding 0
STAT slab_reassign_rescues 0
STAT slab_reassign_chunk_rescues 0
STAT slab_reassign_evictions_nomem 0
STAT slab_reassign_inline_reclaim 0
STAT slab_reassign_busy_items 0
STAT slab_reassign_busy_deletes 0
STAT slab_reassign_running 0
STAT slabs_moved 0
STAT lru_crawler_running 0
STAT lru_crawler_starts 5100
STAT lru_maintainer_juggles 12246
STAT malloc_fails 0
STAT log_worker_dropped 0
STAT log_worker_written 0
STAT log_watcher_skipped 0
STAT log_watcher_sent 0
STAT bytes 0
STAT curr_items 0
STAT total_items 0
STAT slab_global_page_pool 0
STAT expired_unfetched 0
STAT evicted_unfetched 0
STAT evicted_active 0
STAT evictions 0
STAT reclaimed 0
STAT crawler_reclaimed 0
STAT crawler_items_checked 0
STAT lrutail_reflocked 0
STAT moves_to_cold 0
STAT moves_to_warm 0
STAT moves_within_lru 0
STAT direct_reclaims 0
STAT lru_bumps_dropped 0
END
```

I'm running PHP on php-fpm (v7.4) on Ubuntu 20.04 and Apache 2.4. I've installed **memcached (v1.5.22)** via apt along with **php7.4-memcached** package and **libmemcached-tools**

netstat shows it is listening on port 11211

```
tcp    0    0 127.0.0.1:11211  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN 37127/memcached
```

everything runs on localhost so I've kept the default /etc/memcached.conf

```
# run as a daemon
-d 
# memory
-m 64
# connection port
-p 11211
# user
-u memcache
# listen
-l 127.0.0.1
# pidfile
-P /var/run/memcached/memcached.pid
```

the process file exists

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 memcache memcache 6 Jan 31 12:15 /var/run/memcached/memcached.pid
```

and the process runs

```
ps -eaf | grep memcached
memcache   37127       1  0 12:15 ?        00:00:02 /usr/bin/memcached -m 64 -p 11211 -u memcache -l 127.0.0.1 -P /var/run/memcached/memcached.pid
```

service is running (service memcached status)

```
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/memcached.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2024-01-31 12:15:26 CET; 3h 19min ago
       Docs: man:memcached(1)
   Main PID: 37127 (memcached)
      Tasks: 10 (limit: 5846)
     Memory: 2.1M
     CGroup: /system.slice/memcached.service
             └─37127 /usr/bin/memcached -m 64 -p 11211 -u memcache -l 127.0.0.1 -P /var/run/memcached/memcached.pid

Jan 31 12:15:26 www systemd[1]: Started memcached daemon.
```

php module config (/etc/php/7.4/mods-available/memcached.ini)doesn't have too much

```
memcached.ini
; priority=25
extension=memcached.so
; You need to install php-igbinary package to use igbinary serializer
; and php-msgpack to use msgpack serializer
memcached.serializer=php
```

Comment: It is empty because you didn't send any data to it. `cmd_set 0`.

Comment: I thought the application (Wordpress) or PHP would use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For WordPress to utilise your `memcached` service you need to install an appropriate caching plugin (there are dozens of these) and configure it to use your `memcached`.

Comment: Why does every problem in Wordpress need a plugin? PHP will support memcache for session data out of the box. https://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.sessions.php Sure you *could* use memcached for content caching - but you'll have issues using it alongside session storage / a much better approach is to configure caching appropriately and use a varnish or nginx or similar in front of the origin server.

Comment: Enabling PHP session caching in memcache on a single host with a low-traffic site wouldn't give much performance improvement.  Using HTTP Cache control can be high-maintenance with low-quality themes/plugins because many WordPress developers love solving caching issues by throwing in 'Cache-Control: no-cache'.

Comment: ....which is exactly why trying to fix Wordpress plugin issues with more plugins is a bad approach (it's trivial to override a bad caching policy behaviour at the webserver)

Comment: There are options to enable memcached object caching without using heavy plugins by using drop-ins, but they are not for everyone as they lack GUI. Overriding a bad caching policy once is trivial, but when you do it multiple times, it becomes a high-maintenance option.

Comment: If you have to do it multiple times, you are doing it wrong. If you can only configure stuff via a GUI you probably shouldn't be managing internet connected servers. OP clearly has some competence at the command line.

Comment: If you do it only once then you have a static site, not dynamic content with different refresh times. If you are avoiding GUIs then you are excluding an option to delegate cache management to people who manage CMS.  It is a high-maintenance approached.

Comment: You are doing it wrong.